# Integrate Hill equation $\int \frac{x(t)^n}{K + x(t)^n} dt$

Tags: integration

I have to integrate following function

$\int \frac{x(t)^n}{K + x(t)^n} dt $

with  a quite complex function

$x(t) = a b x_0  \left[\frac{1}{\left( b - a \right)} \left(\frac{e^{-bt}}{\left( b - d y_2 \right)} - \frac{e^{-at}}{\left( a - d y_2 \right)} \right) + \frac{ e^{-d y_2t}}{\left( a - d y_2 \right)\left( b - d y_2 \right)} \right]$

Since I have no idea how to solve this integral I started with an easy version of this function $x(t) = e^{-at}$  and I left out the exponent $n$

$\int \frac{e^{-at}}{K + e^{-at}} dt $

via substitution $x = e^{-at}$ I get the following result:

$\int \frac{e^{-at}}{K + e^{-at}} dt  = -\frac{1}{a}\log{(K + e^{-at} )}$

My next step is to solve the integral with the following function $x =e^{-bt} - e^{-at} $

Here the substitution $x =e^{-bt} - e^{-at} $ doesn't work out anymore because numerator and denominator don't cancel out anymore.

$\int \frac{e^{-bt} - e^{-at}}{K + e^{-bt} - e^{-at}} dt$

$\frac{dx}{dt} = -ae^{-at} + b e^{-bt} $

$\int \frac{e^{-bt} - e^{-at}}{K + x} \frac{dx}{-ae^{-at} + b e^{-bt}}$

Here I get stuck.
How do I solve this integral?
I tried to solve the complete integral with Mathematica but I got no solution.

Comment: Look at your title: "integrate Hill's equation" and you give an integral... Can you say where is Hill's equation in there ?

Comment: If you were telling more about the context, we could help you more... The main point is that you are looking for an antiderivative (aka a "closed form for an indefinite integral") : what makes you think that such an antiderivative exist, especially for such a complicated expression ? I'm confident at 99.9% that it doesn't exist (the fact that mathematica doesn't find is an indication, **although you must pay attention** not to give a general exponent $n$, but particular exponents : replace $n$ by $3$, or $4$ or...). Are you sure you want an exact result ?

Comment: I just realized that there are 2 very different Hill's equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_equation). You are talking about the one in biochemistry... that I didn't know (I know the other).

Comment: Im talking about Hill's equation in a biological context. [(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_equation_(biochemistry))]

Comment: Yes I  had understood... But how do you react to my advise not to look at an **exact expression** : I do think it's desparate, and moreover I don't see the interest in the framework of biology.

Comment: I try to solve a differential equation dZ/dt = r(x(t)) Z that models a phagocytosis event of a cell which is populated with a certain protein whose concentration is given by the complicated expression x(t). The rate r(x(t)) is the Hill equation. I wonder if I can solve this differential equation analytically. Maybe it isn't possible.

Comment: In my question I started to simplify my expression by settings n=1 and I already got stuck. So I would be really happy if we would find a solution for n=1. But nevertheless n is a important parameter for the kinetics of my system, so I'm also interested in the general solution.

Comment: 2 general rules of thumb: 1) setting your question at the differential equation level (and staying there the longest possible) and not as an integration issue should be a better approach. 2)  try to obtain a numerical approximation of the solutions of your differential equation in order for example to look for domains of convergence...  etc.

Comment: Ok, after some discussions with my colleagues I will change my system of differential equations, which will change my x(t) and make it simpler. If I get stuck again I will follow your rule of thumb. Thanks!